# Pattern match on a list of tuples

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

If I want to add all the elements of a list of tuples, I get an error with the following

```
let rec addTupLst (xs: 'a * 'a list) =
    match xs with
    | (a, b) :: rst -> a + b + (addTupLst rst)
    | _ -> 0

addTupLst [(1, 2)]
```

I get the warning

> error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
>       'a * 'a list
>   but here has type
>       'b list

Is it not possible to pattern match on a list of tuples this way, or is there another error?

Comment: Put parens around tuple (xs: ( 'a * 'a ) list)

Comment: It's worth noting that you could also just not include the type annotation, and the compiler will infer it correctly in this case.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox Good point. I often find I get more intellisense help with annotations, but in this case obviously got bitten trying to outsmart the compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just forgot a pair of parens

```
let rec addTupLst (xs: ('a * 'a) list) =
     match xs with
     | (a, b) :: rst -> a + b + (addTupLst rst)
     | _ -> 0

addTupLst [(1, 2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you declare the function as taking a `'a * 'a list`, but what you actually want to write is `('a * 'a) list`.

This is one of the reasons why I don't really like the common but (IMO) inconsistent style of using prefix notation for type parameters for some built-in types and postfix notation for the rest. I prefer to write the type as `list<'a * 'a>`.